# Паттерн Builder в С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте, на языке Java построил вот такой шаблон Builder:

```
public class Account {

private String login;
private String password;

private Account() {

}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public static Builder newBuilder() {
    return new Account().new Builder();
}

public class Builder {

    private Builder() {
        // private constructor
    }

    public Builder setLogin(String login) {
        Account.this.login = login;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setPassword(String password) {
        Account.this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public Account build() {
        return Account.this;
    }

}

}
```

Но не получается то же самое реализовать в С++, какие-то проблемы со статиками возникают, может кто поможет в этом или подскажет как? Или вообще кто-то скажет что это невозможно перенести на плюсы.

Comment: нум... код на С++ и проблемы в студию...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Моя телепатия говорит, что ваша проблема в том, что вы используете inner класс. В С++ inner классов нет. Вложенные классы ведут себя так же как Java-вские вложенные статические(nested). Пример:

```
//java
public class Account{
    public static class Builder{

    }
}

//c++
class Account{
public:
    class Builder{

    };
};
```

Попробуйте переписать ваш код так, чтобы Builder был nested, и тогда перевод на C++ станет немного проще.

Конечно без вашего кода на C++ это просто догадки. Но других потенциальных проблем я здесь не вижу.

---

Классический "Строитель" на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Account{
    std::string _login;
    std::string _password;

    Account(const std::string &login,
            const std::string &password):
        _login(login),
        _password(password)
    {}
public:
    class Builder {
        std::string _login;
        std::string _password;
    public:    
        Builder& setLogin(const std::string &login){
            _login = login;
            return *this;
        }

        Builder& setPassword(std::string password){
            _password = password;
            return *this;
        }

        Account* build(){
            return new Account(_login, _password);
        }
    };

    std::string login() const{
        return _login;
    }

    std::string password() const{
        return _password;
    }
};

int main(){
    Account *account = Account::Builder().setLogin("root").setPassword("123456").build();

    std::cout << account->login() << "\n";
    std::cout << account->password() << "\n";
}
```

http://cpp.sh/7yh7m